# Generic extension method for an array does not compile

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, .net-3.5, extension-methods

Populating a request object for a web-service, I need to dynamically add items to some arrays.

I hoped to simplify it by implementing an extension method:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions<T> where T : class
{
    public static T[] Extend<T>(T[] originalArray, T addItem)
    {
        if (addItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("addItem");
        }
        var arr = new[] { addItem };
        if (originalArray == null)
        {
            return arr;
        }
        return originalArray.Concat(arr).ToArray();
    }
}
```

So that this old code:

```
if (foo.bazArr == null)
{
    foo.bazArr  = new[] { baz };
}
else
{
    foo.bazArr = new[] { baz }.Concat(foo.bazArr).ToArray(); // (i know this inserts the new item at the beginning, but that's irrelevant, order doesn't matter)
}
```

could be rewritten as:

```
foo.bazArr = foo.bazArr.Extend(baz); // won't compile
```

The error is: `'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Extend' and no extension method 'Extend' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Whereas calling the extension method directly like so:

```
foo.bazArr = ArrayExtensions<someService.bazType>.Extend(foo.bazArr, baz);
```

compiles fine.

Why is that so? Why can't the compiler infer the type on its own here, if the array is strongly-typed?

---

**EDIT** - correct code below:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static T[] Extend<T>(this T[] originalArray, T addItem) where T : class
    {
        if (addItem == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("addItem");
        }
        var arr = new[] { addItem };
        if (originalArray == null)
        {
            return arr;
        }
        return originalArray.Concat(arr).ToArray(); // although Concat is not recommended for performance reasons, see the accepted answer
    }
}
```

---

For this popular question, here's another good simple example:

```
public static class Extns
    {
    // here's an unbelievably useful array handling extension for games!

    public static T AnyOne<T>(this T[] ra) where T:class
        {
        int k = ra.Length;
        int r = Random.Range(0,k);
        return ra[r];
        // (add your own check, alerts, etc, to this example code)
        }
    }
```

and in use ..

```
someArrayOfSoundEffects.AnyOne().Play();
someArrayOfAnimations.AnyOne().BlendLeft();
winningDisplay.text = successStringsArray.AnyOne() +", " +playerName;
SpawnEnormousRobotAt( possibleSafeLocations.AnyOne() );
```

and so on.  For any array it will give you one random item. Used constantly in games to randomise effects etc. The array can be any type.

Comment: try adding a `this` before `T[] originalArray` in your method param

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Missing `this`:

```
public static T[] Extend<T>(this T[] originalArray, T addItem)
```

Without the `this` *it is not an extension method*.

Additional note: extending an array one item at a time is expensive. A `List<T>` would be far preferable. Check to see if your web-service tools offer lists as an option.

Even with arrays, using `Enumerable.Concat` is probably overkill here; I would simply measure the two arrays, allocate a new one, and use the `CopyTo` method of each to write into place in the new array.

Comment: This is embarassing :)) gosh, I really need that first coffee today. Thank you.

Comment: 1. By the way, the compiler also forced me to move the generic constraint from the class level to the method level. But it works fine when I did that. 2. `A List<T> would be far preferable. Check to see if your web-service tools offer lists as an option.` - I imagine. But we've got other apps using this webservice and changing the type surely would break them here, no? I only expect a few items in the collection anyway (they represent product sizes, so it's never thousands of them).

Comment: @Morawski the list vs array is a client-side thing; doesn't impact the web-service or the serialization at all.

Comment: Accepted as the first and most comprehensive answer.

Comment: I agree that `List<>` is far preferable.  However, I did throw together an extension method that concatenates 2 arrays by allocating a new one and copying both original arrays into it, as Marc described. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Igzu9C

Answer (score 2):

use `this` in defining extension method

```
public static T[] Extend<T>(this T[] originalArray, T addItem)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have missed the "this" keyword